# Copy-paste selection from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel, selection, copy-paste

I am trying to automate a process that involves copy pasting data from one workbook to a new workbook. I've been able to put together the code shows below from snippets found in the forums here, and other places. However, I am receiving a "Runtime error 1004" when attempting to run the procedure. Any suggestions?

```
Option Explicit
Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook, wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
Dim wbName As String
Sub transferit()

wbName = InputBox("Enter name", "name")

'~~> Source/Input Workbook
Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
'~~> Set the relevant sheet from where you want to copy
Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Sheet1")

'~~> Destination/Output Workbook
Set wbO = Workbooks.Add
'~~> Set the relevant sheet to where you want to paste
Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")

With wbO
    '~~>. Save the file
    .SaveAs Filename:="D:\Documents\Output\wbName
End With

With wsI
   Call RangeSelectionPrompt
   Selection.Copy
End With

With wsO
    '~~> Paste it in say Cell A1. Change as applicable
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub RangeSelectionPrompt()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
End Sub
```

Comment: Must be a typo, but there is a " missing at the end of the  `.SaveAs ... ` line.

Comment: And you don't `rng.Select` inside the RangeSelectionPrompt, so the call does nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need global variables? It is unlikely, move them inside the Sub. You didn't concatenate the filename rightly for the .SaveAs, and you did not copy what you was expecting to...
Here is my code, ther is still some control of errors missing.

```
    Sub transferit()

        Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook, wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
        Dim wbName As String
        wbName = InputBox("Enter name", "name")

        '~~> Source/Input Workbook
        Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
        '~~> Set the relevant sheet from where you want to copy
        Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Sheet1")

        '~~> Destination/Output Workbook
        Set wbO = Workbooks.Add
        '~~> Set the relevant sheet to where you want to paste
        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")

        With wbO
            '~~>. Save the file
            .SaveAs Filename:="D:\Documents\Output\" & wbName
        End With

        RangeSelectionPrompt.Copy

        With wsO
            '~~> Paste it in say Cell A1. Change as applicable
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
    End Sub

    Function RangeSelectionPrompt() As Range
        Set RangeSelectionPrompt = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    End Function


    RangeSelectionPrompt.Copy

    With wsO
        '~~> Paste it in say Cell A1. Change as applicable
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub

Function RangeSelectionPrompt() As Range
    Set RangeSelectionPrompt = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
End Function
```